# Count string with the first character match

Tags: python, regex

Looking for a way to count the string who have "#" as first character.

```
import re

def y():
    with open('test.conf', 'r') as rf:
    hitcount = 0
        for line in rf:
            if re.search(r'#*', line):
            hit_count = hit_count + 1
    print(hit_count)
```

when I used the script...it count all the string who have #, wherever it was place.

Below are the test.conf. The result should be only 4.

```
#config-version=FWF60C-5.02-FW-build754-170421:opmode=0:vdom=0:user=lorenzo.aspera
#conf_file_ver=42514
#buildno=0754
#global_vdom=1
config sy###stem global
   END####
```

Comment: Hi, can you please clarify why you've accepted an answer that does not answer your question? You're trying to count _lines_ that begin with a pound sign, not words. Or else, you'd not get 4 like you expect. Please take another look at the answers.

Comment: Just want to count who start with "#", i'm not familiar with "startwith".

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, you shouldn't be using `re.search`... actually, you shouldn't be using `re` AT ALL. Why not just `str.startswith`?

```
count = 0
with open('test.conf', 'r') as rf:
    for line in rf:
        if line.startswith('#'):
            count += 1
```

```
print(count)
4
```

If you're hell bent on using regex, then, use `re.match` instead, that anchors searches to the start of the string (`re.search` does *not* - unless you use the SOL anchor `^` inside your pattern - that's why you were observing spurious counts).

Alternatively, I like conciseness (but not at the cost of readability of course), so I'd go for `sum` with a comprehension.

```
with open('test.conf', 'r') as rf:
    count = sum(line.startswith('#') for line in rf)
```

```
print(count)
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach and your description of the problem seems slightly different.

To clarify, which of the bottom 2 options is what you want?

1. find any lines with # before it
2. find any words with # before it?

if its (1), I believe that coldspeed's answer will serve the purpose.

if its (2), then the steps are as follows:

Load file and delimit whitespaces and newlines:

```
words = open(file).read().split()
```

Check through each word for #

```
count=0
for (i in words): 
    if(i.startswith("#")):
        count+=1
print(count)
```

Comment: Besides that, there's a lot wrong with this answer. Please don't encourage opening files without explicitly closing them or using context managers. Also, please don't put parentheses where necessary.